# Javascript. It keeps printing 4 times

Tags: javascript

It keeps printing 4 times.

Code:

```
var friends = {};
 friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};

var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
};
list(friends.bill);
```

I want a result to be this:

```
{ firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
```

not

```
Bill
Gates
(206) 555-5555
[ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ]
```

and not

```
      { firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
{ firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
{ firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
{ firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
```

what will I do?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you are iterating over the properties of the object and printing the object for every property. You have four properties (`firstName`, `lastName`, `number` and `address`), so the object is printed four times.

If you don't want to do that, then don't loop. Replace

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

with

```
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: what if I want to print it 2 times?

Comment: `console.log(obj); console.log(obj);`

Comment: `console.log` still won't render it out as a string the way that's desired - for example, the address field will just show as `Array[4]`.

Comment: @sphanley: I don't think the OP wants to output a string.

Comment: @FelixKling Fair enough - I guess there's a degree of ambiguity as to what OP is expecting to be in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers suggest simply using `console.log` on `friends.bill`. This is close, but if you try it, I'm not sure that it does exactly what you need: since `address` is a nested array, it's going to print out `Array[4]` as its value rather than printing its internal values as well.

The ideal way to achieve what I believe you want, which (if I'm understanding correctly) is to print a string representation of a JavaScript object, is to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(friends.bill));
```

This will first convert your object into a string representation with all field names and values as strings, then write that converted string to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var friends = {};
 friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
```

`friends.bill` is a object with `firstName, lastName, number, address`. If you want the below result.

```
    { firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Gates',
  number: '(206) 555-5555',
  address: [ 'One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052' ] }
```

You can directly use `console.log(friends.bill)` to get the desired result.

What you are doing is iterating over the object, so the loop will run over the properties, `friends.bill` has four properties(firstName, lastName, number, address) so the loop will run four times print the `friends.bill` object.

```
for(var prop in friends.bill) {
    console.log(prop); 
}
```